# Problem with SharePoint calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a field (Status Update Date) that should be updated with the current date/time when another field (Status) is changed.  However, whenever ANY field in the row (datasheet view) is updated the Status Update Date us updating to the current date/time.  Any ideas on how to ensure the field is only updated with current date/time when the Status field is updated?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Status),1/2/1900,TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with a formula. One option is to develop an event receiver and compare the old value of the status field with the new value. If they are different, you can update de "Status Update Field".

Comment: That makes sense but requires visual studio, which I don't have access to.  Is there any other way?  Also, there are references to exactly what I'm doing all over the internet so I assumed I just had my syntax wrong or something.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Perhaps you can use a workflow and another column to store the old value of the state. So you can try the workflow to make the comparission, and the update.

Comment: I'm really trying to stick with the calculated field since others seem to have gotten that to work but mine updates the status update date when ANY field is changed.  any ideas?

Comment: You cannot do it with calculated field

Answer (score 0):

Your Calculated Formula is re-evaluated on every Item Update, thats just how it works.

Indeed a Workflow and an extra Column to store the previous Status value is the way to go.

On SP2013 you can also do it with CSR - Client Side Rendering Javacript code which sets a Date field when Status is changed.. but that requires an extra Column to store the previous Status as well to make it fool-proof

Comment: But using CSR, won't that be just for display? As in, it won't actually change the column value.

Comment: So they really have this sharepoint instance locked down.  I can't even add a workflow.  Any other ideas?  I'm about to give up on this.